# How to get the color of a FullCalendar event when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm setting the background color of Fullcalendar events (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) like so:

```
 eventSources: [
               {
                   events: [ 
                       {
                           title: 'Event1',
                           start: '2014-07-05'
                       },
                       {
                           title: 'Event2',
                           start: '2014-07-19'
                       }

                   ],
                   color: 'green',     
                   textColor: 'black' 
               },
```

When I click on the event I want to be able to determine what the color is (So I can change it to another color).

I'm doing the following with no luck:

```
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view)
    {  
      var color1 = calEvent.color; //color1 = undefined

      var color2 = $(this).css('border-color');//color2=0,255,0 in chrome, undefined in IE
    }
```

How do I get the actual color that was set in the  first place? i.e in the example it would be 'green'.

Comment: Is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/k9Ct3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to be able to 'get' the color that was set for the event. So in your example I want to know that the color was green, how can I do that?

Comment: Sure, but you will not get green but the RGB, see: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Y7Dm2/

Answer (score 0):

Is working fine in all browsers, but you will not get `green`, but the RGB.

Code:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert($(this).css('background-color'));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Y7Dm2/